# Germany: Family Reunion Visa: Passport valid till Feb 2020

Tags: germany, eu, long-stay-visas, mumbai

My spouse was recently approved with Germany Blue Card (long term employment visa). It is valid from 1st June 2019. He has not traveled to Germany yet. I have appointment at German Consulate, Mumbai, India in next week. I am applying for family reunion visa. I could not attend interview with my husband due to to issues with appointment dates.

My passport is valid till Feb 2020. I have not renewed my passport due to issues with Visa application interview dates. I read on consulate's website that passport has to be valid for 1 year.

What I am planning is:
- Appear for interview with current passport (valid till Feb 2020)
- After interview I get around 2 months to receive approval. During this time I will renew my passport. I will inform interview officer that while submitting passport for stamping (after approval), I will submit new passport.

Please let me know if it would work. Has anyone done this before?

If you require more information, kindly let me know.

Comment: For family reunification, you will get better answers at Expatriates Stack Exchange. People on Travel Stack Exchange can answer questions about short-term visa.